# what is kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=303

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, post, get

I tried to post my textFiled data to Server.but when posting I got this error:

> Error: Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=303 "The operation couldn’t be completed. 
>       (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303.)" UserInfo=0x13786c60 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.3.125:8090/SaveDollar/rest/deals/add, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.3.125:8090/SaveDollar/rest/deals/add}

I do not understand this error.

Comment: what you set in HTTPMethod ?

Comment: @iBhavin  [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

Comment: just set it to POST .

Comment: @iBhavin k but i need get responce also

Comment: @iBhavin i have given request method  GET in Services

Comment: have you set it to POST ???

Comment: are you trying to upload something to your server ?

Comment: @pawan YES upload and get Response also

Comment: @pawan Please give me any idea about my problem

Comment: you should use POST request for sending some data to server. after that you can get response from server(like :- image upload successfully or any other custom message).

Answer (score 7):

Is a parsing error from the server, when its response can't be parsed. You can look up the error codes in the [CFNetworkErrors reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cfnetwork/cfnetworkerrors).

Make sure you set HTTPMethod to POST

Comment: thanks for Relay i have given request method  GET in Services

Comment: For all you Swift users, the link above does include the numeric codes, but only when you select "Objective-C" or "Both" as your language preference (top of web page).

Answer (score 6):

```
kCFErrorHTTPParseFailure      = 303,
```

> The HTTP server response could not be parsed.

From 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cfnetwork/cfnetworkerrors/kcferrorhttpparsefailure