# Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=303 What does this error code means?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

Getting the below error frequently from server.

Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=303 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 303.)" UserInfo=0x18a41d20 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://s3.amazonaws.com/Multimedia/Audios/20150428/AUDIO_CB0F4CAF-C921-46B6-AEC2-1FA6B7FB91A0.wav, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://s3.amazonaws.com/Multimedia/Audios/20150428/AUDIO_CB0F4CAF-C921-46B6-AEC2-1FA6B7FB91A0.wav}

Can any one tell me what is the cause for the issues?

Regards,
Chandrika

Comment: Google for "Status 303".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a kCFErrorHTTPParseFailure error. Could you provide more details such as:

-Are you trying to upload or download a file?

-Are you using AWSS3TransferManager, AWSS3 or AWSPresignedURL to perform the uploading or downloading?

-Does it happen every time? If not, what is the percentage?

-A code snippet

Answer (score 1):

It's a parsing issue. You can look up the error code here (Under CFNetworkErrors Constants):
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/CFNetworkErrors/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CFNetworkErrors

And the issue has also been discussed here:
[what is kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=303](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077284/what-is-kcferrordomaincfnetwork-code-303)

In short words, the server is raising this error because you probably have encoding issues or perhaps is using the wrong HTTP method.

Comment: Am getting this error in Amazon SDK which is integrated in iOS app

Comment: Are you using the most recent version?

Comment: Can you provide some more information about the SDK or/and how the issue occur? I've explained what the `kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=303` is in general. I think in order to proceed, more details is needed on this specific case.

Comment: Am using AWSS3TransferManager upload /download request class. It happens 3 out of 10 times.